# Docker hub private repo image pull access denied on azure service via github action

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, github-actions, dockerhub

Here below is the YML which azure provide while creating app service
name: Build and deploy container app to Azure Web App - dev-MasterBackend

on:
push:
branches:
- dev
workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
build:
runs-on: 'ubuntu-latest'

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Set up Docker Buildx
  uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

- name: Log in to registry
  uses: docker/login-action@v1
  with:
    registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
    username: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_ContainerUsername_5c13827d32e9418391a1f094e5723b88 }}
    password: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_ContainerPassword_a90eeb6bc307427f8a87ea0961dffdb9 }}

- name: build the docker image
  run: docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml build

- name: docker push 
  run: docker push curiousa/masterbackend:curio-master
```

deploy:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
needs: build
environment:
name: 'production'
url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

```
steps:   

- name: Deploy to Azure Web App
  id: deploy-to-webapp
  uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
  with:
    app-name: 'dev-MasterBackend'
    slot-name: 'production'
    publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile_c97a2c2da444408dadd0ab1ca26f78e4 }}
    images: 'index.docker.io/${{ secrets.AzureAppService_ContainerUsername_5c13827d32e9418391a1f094e5723b88 }}/curiousa/masterbackend:curio-master'
```

but github action pipeline is successful but getting the below error on the azure log stream

2023-02-05T18:56:39.502Z ERROR - Pulling docker image index.docker.io/abhijeetcurio/curiousa/masterbackend:curio-master failed:
2023-02-05T18:56:41.356Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"pull access denied for abhijeetcurio/curiousa/masterbackend, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied"}

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75358089/edit) your post and [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) using code blocks. Also, add the logs of the successful login in GHA and verify if that user already has the access to that resource and has adequate privileges.Thanks!

Comment: @Azeem all the privileges and access are there.